# Angular Universal: Do I need to install the npm packages on the server?

Tags: angular, universal, angular-universal

If I create a plain Angular app (e. g. with Angular CLI) the build puts all the Javascript in some bundles. These bundles contain all my custom code and also the code of the npm packages, on which my app is depending on (e.g. Angular core, moment).

Now I'm using Universal to pre-render my angular app. The build process creates a   main.bundle.js, which is reference in the server.js (https://angular.io/guide/universal). Is it right, that this bundle does not contain the code of the referenced npm packages? I have to install all this packages on the server, where I run my Universal, again?

OR am I just doing something wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that's not true. You don't need to install the npm packages to run the server. The `main.bundle.js` contains all that is required. For e.g., here is a Dockerfile that builds the Angular project in one stage and in the next stage it runs the server. Here, the npm packages are installed only in the build stage. In the next stage where the server is run, simply the dist folder is copied and **no** npm package is installed.

```
FROM node:8.10.0 AS ausbuilder
RUN useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash aus; \
    chown -R aus /home/aus
USER aus
WORKDIR /home/aus
COPY aus/ /home/aus
RUN mkdir /home/aus/.npm; \
    npm config set prefix /home/aus/.npm; \
    npm install --quiet --no-progress -g webpack@3.11.0; \
    npm install --quiet --no-progress -g @angular/cli@1.7.2; \
    npm install --quiet --no-progress;
ENV PATH=/home/aus/.npm/bin:$PATH
RUN npm run build; \
    webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --no-progress

FROM keymetrics/pm2:8-alpine
RUN adduser -h /home/aus -s /bin/bash aus; \
    chown -R aus /home/aus
USER aus
WORKDIR /home/aus
COPY --from=ausbuilder /home/aus/dist /home/aus/dist
EXPOSE 4000/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["pm2-runtime","start","/home/aus/dist/server.js"]
```

Comment: Thanks for that confirmation. Do you have any idea what I may do wrong. The server.js need some packages like express, but I do not get why I have to install packages which are used by the angular app itself?

Comment: Have you followed the official guide at https://angular.io/guide/universal, while setting up Angular universal. You need to install the following npm packages in your Angular project for Universal, `npm install --save @angular/platform-server @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader ts-loader @nguniversal/express-engine`. When you install these in your Angular project, they would go to your `main.bundle.js` and then in your server.ts, you just need to import the express

Comment: Additionally, when I first followed this guide to create the Universal app, I observed the following

Webpack 3 is not compatible with ts-loader versions higher than 3.5.0. At the time of developing this, the latest version of Angular CLI is 1.7.2 which uses Webpack 3.*. Hence, while setting up Angular Universal, install ts-config@3.5.0
webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin plugin syntax used in the documentation doesn't seem to work with Webpack 3.* and hence I had to use the alternative syntax. 
My server.ts: https://github.com/saptarshibasu/angular-universal-setup/blob/master/aus/server.ts

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the npm packages for **server side rendering** on the server where you are doing the **rendering** or **pre-rendering** (they are both different). From what you said, you want to use pre-rendering. In that case, you need to install the required npm packages on the server where you will pre-generate the html pages (that can be your staging server for instance).

```
npm install --save @angular/platform-server @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader ts-loader @nguniversal/express-engine
```

Once you've prerendered all pages, you need to copy these pages (as well as the js files that were first generated when you built your app) onto your production server. From there, you can serve these pages with any webserver you want (nginx,apache, express,..), since it's all static (html/js) content. You do not need npm packages or even node here (apart if you want to serve them using express)

Otherwise, if you want to use on the fly rendering, then yes you will need express and npm packages on the production server

Answer (score 0):

Generated `dist/server/main.js` contains references to all Node packages your app uses. If you will trigger express server **without** transpiling it by webpack - then yes. You will require npm packages to be installed.

But if you will create server **.ts** file and provide it to webpack for transpiling via `webpack --config webpack.server.config.js` from the guide, then you will get usually huge `dist/server.js` file generated

This file contains all your dependencies merged into single file and thus **doesn't** need packages to be present. Executing `node dist/server` will launch your application and it's self contained. I.e. you could remove anything except `dist` folder and it will work.